# How do I clear the "s" permission on a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I have a directory that is showing up with the permission mask `drwsrwsr-x`.  When I try to reset the permissions to `755` the S still remains.

What is the "s" and why cant I change the permissions back to 775 (`drwxrwxr-x`)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The s you are seeing in the "execute" position in the user and group column are the SetUID (Set User ID on Execution) and SetGID (Set Group ID on execution) bits.

Unix file permissions are actually a 4-digit octal number `SUGO`

- **S** controls the SetUID (4), SetGID (2) and "Sticky" (1) bits
- **U** controls Read(4)/Write(2)/Execute(1) bits for the file owner
- **G** controls the Read/Write/Execute bits for the file's group
- **O** controls the Read/Write/Execute bits for everyone else.

You can remove the setuid bits from your directory with `chmod ug-s directory`, or `chmod 0755 directory`

For more information see the man page for `chmod`, and [this Wikipedia page about the SetUID bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

Comment: It's "sgid" (no "u").

Comment: "what is the drwsrwsrwx?" <- check again

Comment: `chmod 0755` does *not* clear the setuid bit, at least not on Linux. I'm currently testing on other systems.

Comment: POSIX says that it's implementation defined for file types other than regular files whether `chmod` with an octamal mode clears the setuid, setgid and vtx bits.

Comment: To clear the setuid bit on a directory on Linux, use `chmod 00755`; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393531/46851

Answer (score 42):

[setuid and setgid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)

> setuid and setgid (short for set user ID upon execution and set group ID upon execution, respectively) are Unix access rights flags that allow users to run an executable with the permissions of the executable's owner or group. They are often used to allow users on a computer system to run programs with temporarily elevated privileges in order to perform a specific task. While the assumed user id or group id privileges provided are not always elevated, at a minimum they are specific.

To remove the setuid and setgid bits numerically, you must prefix the bit-pattern with a `0` (e.g.: `0775` becomes `00775`).

Run to delete setuid and setgid:

```
chmod 00775 path
```

or

```
chmod a-st path
```

Comment: It's on directory not file

Comment: a directory is also a file in a unix filesystem, what ooshro says is completely correct

Comment: yes it's all a file, but the description does not fit as you dont execute something that looks like drwxrwxr-x :|

Comment: In unix, the inode is the thing that gets the permissions.

Comment: GNU chmod does not clear the setuid and setgid bytes on directories when you execute it with an octamal mode. POSIX allows this behaviour.

Comment: @FUZxxl thanks! that was driving me crazy. Do you happen to know where it's documented?

Comment: @GnP It says so in the man page.

Comment: All right for clearing, but how do you set it? Does it suffice to `chmod 6770` (for instance), or do you have to prepend the 0 (`chmod 06770`)?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to ooshro's answer...

If you use suid or sgid permissions on a directory, any files created inside that directory will have the same owner (if suid) or group (sgid) as the directory in question.

I use that for my home Samba share.  The base directory is owned by user nobody and group olympia, and the permissions are 2770.  So you have to be in the group olympia to read or write anything below that directory, and it will make sure olympia is the owning group of everything below it.  I also have Samba configured to use a dirmask of 2770 and a filemask of 660 to keep the permissions correct all the way down the tree.